# If I input an element in a list, how to print the next element of that list?

Tags: python, list

```
list = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

ch = input('Please Enter a number:\n')

if ch in list:
    print('next element of that number is :' + list[ch + 1]) #please rectify or add here
else:
    print("it's not in the list")
```

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  You haven't looked up how to find a given value in a list.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: `list[list.index(ch) + 1]` you want something like this.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will work just perfect for what you're trying to do.

```
list = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

ch = input('Please Enter a number:\n')

try:
    i = list.index(ch)
    if i < len(list)-1:
        print('next element of that number is :' + list[i+1]) 
    else:
        print("This is the last item of list")
except:
    print("item not present in  list")
```

Comment: Why call `.index` twice?

Comment: That's not ideal code but it solves the problem.